# Regexpression for check if string is locale like locale_Culture

Tags: php, regex, localization, internationalization

I want to check if string is locale like `en`, `uk`, etc. It I do by this reg exp:

```
/^[a-z]{2}$/
```

But I want to do this with locales what consis from locale and culture, like `en_US`, or `en_EN`. My knowledge of regular expressions is too pure to do this. Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the right one :)

```
/^[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}$/
```

Answer (score 4):

What kind of locale identifier do you want to validate for?
There is more than one.

For instance on Linux you have en_US.UTF-8
BCP 47 allows for way more complex stuff (for instance rs_Latn_RS, or ja@calendar=japanese) (https://tools.ietf.org/html/bcp47)

If you want a PHP locale, then you want the BCP 47 syntax (RFC 4646 is part of BCP 47):

> Locales are identified using RFC 4646 language tags

http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php

If that is the case, then it is probably too complex to handle with a regexp.

Comment: I think "you can't do it with regexp" kind of answers the question :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
/^[a-z]{2}(?:_[A-Z]{2})?$/
```

**Explanation:**

- **^** notes the start of file/string
- **[a-z]{2}** checks for `en`, `br` etc.
- **(?:_[A-Z]{2})?** optional non-capturing group to match `en_US`, `en_EN`
  etc.
- **$** notes the end of file/string

To make the second part mandatory, omit the latest `?`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
/^[a-z]{2}_[A-Z]{2}$/
```

Comment: Mhm, i guess, my bad.

Comment: @Djip It matches but doesn't match the whole. This mean it still matches.These are two different concepts. Your code needs an extra '$' to determine end of matching (opposite to '^').